# gmail not posting amp form

Tags: c#, post, gmail, amp-html

I'm making a dynamic email with two forms, the first of which has one button and a hidden field with a predefined value (the stem) that will be posted to the backend and send the OTP of a specific user. Once the first form is successfully submitted, I unhide the second form to accept the OTP, which has been validated, and the points for that specific customer are redeemed if the OTP is posted to the backend. The issue is that form submission works fine in playground, but when I send the same HTML to gmail, it wraps my original request and does not hit my server.

Here is my Html,

```
`<!doctype html>
<html amp4email data-css-strict>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
      <script custom-element="amp-form" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-form-0.1.js" async></script>
      <!--<script custom-template="amp-mustache" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-mustache-0.2.js" async></script>-->
      <script async custom-element="amp-bind" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-bind-0.1.js"></script>
      <meta name="a" content="width=device-width">
      <style amp4email-boilerplate>body{visibility:hidden}
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form method="post"
         action-xhr="action"
         on="submit-success:form2.show,form1.hide,AMP.setState({'otpReference': event.response.Data.OtpReference})" id="form1">
         <input type=hidden value="wdDDiFCG" name="stem">
         <input type="submit" value="Redeem Now!">
      </form>
      <form id="form2" method="post" action-xhr="action" hidden>
         <input type=hidden value="wdDDiFCG" name="stem" >
         <input type=hidden [value]="otpReference" name="otpReference" >
         <fieldset>
            <label>
            <span>Please enter OTP:</span>
            <input type="text"
               name="otp"
               required>
            </label>
            <input type="submit"
               value="Submit & Redeem">
         </fieldset>
         <button on="tap:form1.show,form2.hide">Back</button>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>`
```

I get the following errors in the Google Chrome console.

`[amp-form] Failed to parse response JSON: SyntaxError: "undefined" is not valid JSON.  [amp-form] Form submission failed: 404.`

I searched for solutions on the web but didn't find a satisfactory solution. I don't know exactly what is blocking my form from posting from Gmail.

I configured "CORS" settings as below:

`<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />  <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="600" />  <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="https://mail.google.com" /> <add name="AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin" value="https://mail.google.com/dynamic-email/relay/v2/index.html" /> <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" /> <add name="Access-Control-Expose-headers" value="AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin" /> <add name="AMP-Email-Allow-Sender" value="amp@gmail.dev"/>`

I've also set the **AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin** value to "**https://mail.google.com**." but it didn't work.

The Access-Control-Allow-Origin value was also set to "*", but it still didn't work.